# Do working drafts of image files belong in the android project folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, organization

I was having a tough time finding an answer to this on google:

I have a few files that do not belong in the apk, such as Inkscape (svg) files that I rasterize, and Gimp (xcf) files that I use to export png files. I want to keep things organized in the most compact and logical way, but I do not want my working drafts to become part of the apk file.

Is the correct way to keep another folder for each project (outside of the project folder) for these working drafts of media files? Maybe I'm over-thinking this.. I just want to use best practices, and my current method (using an extra folder for every project) feels cumbersome.

Is there a way to ignore a folder within the actual android/eclipse project folder? I would love to know what other people are doing to stay organized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place the files within your project in a folder that

- isnt a source folder (src and gen)
- isnt your assets or res folder

& They wont be included with your build (apk)

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly to such a noobish question.